# What does it mean intent.setFlags(805306368) in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I used this line of code to launch my app 
 `intent.setFlags(805306368);` and it perfectly launches the app and resumes it if it is running in background. But what does the integer number 805306368 mean?
What does it do to resume my app if it is running.Does anyone know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`805306368` is equivalent to `0x30000000` in hex and `0x30000000` is used  to open the `Intent` with the following flags :

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

So, its equivalent to use the above combination or `0x30000000`.

From Android docs [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) :

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP = 0x20000000
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 0x10000000
```

So, the combination [results](https://ideone.com/9UlW9X) in `0x30000000`

Also, as mentioned in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) the new task flag  i.e,`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is used to achieve the following behaviour:

> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in.

and the single top flag i.e, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is used to achieve the following behaviour, as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) :

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

So, these flags help to resume your activity and prevents from opening a new activity.

Comment: Excellent answer @Ashish... +1

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation